# How to cast nested struct in Java Spark (Unsupported NullType)

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, hive

I am loading mongodb to hive table and trying to solve Unsupported NullType when saveAsTable.
Sample data schema

```
root
 |-- level1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- level2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- level3_1: null (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- level3_2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- level4: null (nullable = true)
```

I tried functions.lit like

```
df = df.withColumn("level1.level2.level3_1", functions.lit("null").cast("string"));
       .withColumn("level1.level2.level3_2.level4", functions.lit("null").cast("string"));
```

but the result is like

```
root
 |-- level1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- level2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- level3_1: null (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- level3_2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- level4: null (nullable = true)
 |-- level1.level2.level3_1: string (nullable = false)
 |-- level1.level2.level3_2.level4: string (nullable = false)
```

I also checked df.na().fill() but this seems not changing the schema.

The desired result is

```
root
 |-- level1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- level2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- level3_1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- level3_2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- level4: string (nullable = true)
```

and that I can use loaded mongodb data save as table to hive

Does anyone have worked on this and could give me some advise that how to cast nested nulltype or how to deal with nulltype in java. Think of a systematic/general solution that can scale for more complex data.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

One idea is a creating schema with StringType and read data with the schema.

```
StructType schema = createStructType(Arrays.asList(
    createStructField("level1", createStructType(Arrays.asList(
        createStructField("level2", createStructType(Arrays.asList(
            createStructField("level3_1", StringType, true),
            createStructField("level3_2", createArrayType(createStructType(Arrays.asList(
                createStructField("level4", StringType, true)))), true)
            )), true))), true)));

// Replace new ArrayList<>() to your dataset.
Dataset<Row> df = ss.createDataFrame(new ArrayList<>(), schema);
df.printSchema();
```

```
root
 |-- level1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- level2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- level3_1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- level3_2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- level4: string (nullable = true)
```

EDIT:

I added more intuitive example here to deliver my thought. I hope it helps you.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    SparkSession ss = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate();

    // Step1) read your mongoDB data. (I added NullType field 'level' manually for explaination.
    // https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python/read-from-mongodb/
    Dataset<Row> data = ss.read().json("test.json").withColumn("level", lit(null));
    data.printSchema();

    StructType schema = createStructType(Arrays.asList(
        createStructField("_id", LongType, true),
        createStructField("level", StringType, true)));

    // Step2) create newData using schema you defined. 
    Dataset<Row> newData = ss.createDataFrame(data.collectAsList(), schema);
    newData.printSchema();

    // Step3) load newData to Hive
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what if I want to have the data? because this is change the schema but the goal is to load the mongodb data and save as table in hive

Comment: And think of what if the schema is complex, is there a way to do it systematically

Comment: Yes It's looks not good way if schema is complex but I think It is a problem when we use spark with java. You don't need to create schema and can use even more easy library to do this with scala or python.

Comment: I am very much appreciate your example. This is very precious information for java users. What if, say we do another way around, map the rows and if the row has null and change it? do you think this approach would work? If you are familiar with mapping the rows would be the best.